# order by and sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in trouble with a basical stored procedure, unfortunately I am not a sql expert, what I am trying to do is sort offers result by 2 parameters, `@OrderBy` and `@SortOrder`, however the result is sorted only on the result of the sub-query.
For example:

```
exec [dbo].[GetTest2] @Page=0,@Limit=150,@OrderBy=N'NetworkName',@SortOrder=N'asc'
```

it works as expected, but

```
exec [dbo].[GetTest2] @Page=0,@Limit=15,@OrderBy=N'NetworkName',@SortOrder=N'asc'
```

doesn't works because the subquery doesn't return all the records.

how can I sort over the entire recordset?

```
USE [MyContext]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTest2] 
    @Page int = 0,
    @Limit int = 10,
    @OrderBy nvarchar(50) = 'OfferId',
    @Name nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @SortOrder nvarchar(50) = 'asc'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @OrderBy) AS ROWNUMBER, 
                  COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Total_Rows], 
                  a.Name AS NetworkName, 
                  o.*  

                  FROM offers AS o 
                    left outer join AffiliateNetworks AS a ON o.NetworkId = a.Id

                  WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR o.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' )) AS Paged 
    WHERE 

    Paged.ROWNUMBER > @Limit * @Page AND 
    Paged.ROWNUMBER <= (@Limit * @Page) + @Limit

    order by 
                    case 
                        when @SortOrder <> 'asc' then NULL
                        when @OrderBy = 'Name' then Name
                        end ASC,
                    case 
                        when @SortOrder <> 'asc' then NULL
                        when @OrderBy = 'NetworkName' then NetworkName
                        end ASC,
                    case 
                        when @SortOrder <> 'desc' then NULL
                        when @OrderBy = 'Name' then Name
                        end DESC,
                    case 
                        when @SortOrder <> 'desc' then NULL
                        when @OrderBy = 'NetworkName' then NetworkName
                        end DESC

END
```

Comment: SQL doesn't support this construct.

With stored procedures, the SQL Dialect is important.  Which dialect of SQL are you using?  Oracle?  DB2?  SQLServer? Postgres?  etc

Comment: I am using ms sqlserver, it's support this statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider adding the sorting within the ROW_NUMBER to keep the paging consistent. I wrapped the sub-query in a CTE to make it a little easier to read.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTest2] 
    @Page int = 0,
    @Limit int = 10,
    @OrderBy nvarchar(50) = 'OfferId',
    @Name nvarchar(100) = NULL,
    @SortOrder nvarchar(50) = 'asc'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH Paged AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'ASC'
                    THEN (CASE @OrderBy WHEN = 'Name' THEN Name WHEN 'NetworkName' THEN a.Name END) END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'DESC'
                    THEN (CASE @OrderBy WHEN = 'Name' THEN Name WHEN 'NetworkName' THEN a.Name END) END DESC)
            ) AS ROWNUMBER,
            COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Total_Rows],
            a.Name AS NetworkName,
            o.*
        FROM offers AS o 
            left outer join AffiliateNetworks AS a ON o.NetworkId = a.Id
        WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR o.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' )
    )
        SELECT *
        FROM Paged
        WHERE ROWNUMBER - (@Limit * @Page) BETWEEN 1 AND @Limit
        ORDER BY ROWNUMBER
END
GO
```

As mentioned in comments, `ROW_NUMBER` may not be best construct for paging in later versions of SQL Server. If you are using at least 2012 or higher, then you can use the `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` to do your paging. Then your query becomes something like this:

```
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Total_Rows],
        CASE @OrderBy WHEN = 'Name' THEN o.Name WHEN 'NetworkName' THEN a.Name END AS SortName,
        a.Name AS NetworkName,
        o.*
    FROM offers AS o 
        left outer join AffiliateNetworks AS a ON o.NetworkId = a.Id
    WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR o.Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%' )
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'ASC' THEN SortName ELSE NULL END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortOrder = 'DESC' THEN SortName ELSE NULL END DESC
    OFFSET (@Page * @Limit) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @Limit ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Good answer +1 but, if there are lots of rows, maybe a temporary table would be better than a CTE.

Comment: Fixed small syntax error (left in extra "=" in case)

Comment: @Jodrell I agree that you need to consider performance impact of paging against large tables, but I also imagine ROW_NUMBER writing to tempdb of large tables entirely can also cause issues. OFFSET/FETCH NEXT is likely the much better choice for large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am sorry but it does't compile at all

Comment: Sorry, trying to do it as psuedo code in notepad :) Just fixed issue with CASE missing end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
order by 
                    case 
                        when @OrderBy = 'Name' and @SortOrder = 'asc' then Name
                        when @OrderBy = 'NetworkName' and @SortOrder = 'asc' then NetworkName
                        end ASC,

                    case when @OrderBy = 'Name' and @SortOrder = 'desc' then Name
                         when @OrderBy = 'NetworkName' and @SortOrder = 'desc' then NetworkName
                         end DESC
```

Comment: thank's a lot but your answer is not related to the question